# Group By a specific value on a column for faster execution time - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

This code works perfectly but the execution time takes long, because the `attendance_03` has the same count of rows as `working_schedule_03` which really need each rows because `working_schedule_03` have a shift schedule like 8:00, 9:00 and so on and it is where `attendance_03` base its late employees, `attendance_03` have the actual time in of an employee, now what I want is to group some values in multiple columns in `working_schedule_03` table which is `emp_id` column and `t_in`(shift schedule) column because the `t_in` is not fixed, employees changes schedule every week and others have fixed sched and lastly eve column which have "Regular" value and to ungroup the "Rest day" values so `attendance_03` will not get the rows from eve column which have rest day values. thanks!

```
 SELECT 
    a.emp_id, COUNT(a.a_id) AS Cymon, b.t_in AS mt_in, c.last_name, c.first_name, e.dept_name, e.dept_id, f.l_id, f.loc
 FROM
     attendance_03 AS a
    LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT * FROM working_schedule_03 WHERE d BETWEEN 16 AND 31 AND Y = 2015 AND eve="Regular") AS b ON b.emp_id = a.emp_id AND b.d = a.dd
    LEFT JOIN 
      employee_personal_info AS c ON c.emp_id = a.emp_id 
    LEFT JOIN 
      employee_information AS d ON d.emp_id = a.emp_id 
    LEFT JOIN 
      departments AS e ON e.dept_id = d.department 
    LEFT JOIN 
      employee_location AS f ON f.l_id = d.loc 
  WHERE a.yy = 2015 AND a.dd BETWEEN 16 AND 31 AND b.eve = "Regular" AND e.dept_id != 22
      AND
  CASE 
    WHEN b.t_in = "07:00" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "07" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 59 
    WHEN b.t_in = "07:30" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "07" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 31 AND 59 OR HOUR(a.t_in) = "08" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 30
    WHEN b.t_in = "08:00" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "08" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 59 
    WHEN b.t_in = "08:30" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "08" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 31 AND 59 OR HOUR(a.t_in) = "09" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 30
    WHEN b.t_in = "09:00" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "09" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 59 
    WHEN b.t_in = "10:00" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "10" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 59 
    WHEN b.t_in = "13:00" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "13" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 59 
    WHEN b.t_in = "15:00" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "15" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 59 
    WHEN b.t_in = "16:00" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "16" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 59 
    WHEN b.t_in = "17:00" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "17" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 59 
    WHEN b.t_in = "19:00" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "19" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 59 
    WHEN b.t_in = "19:30" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "19" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 31 AND 59 OR HOUR(a.t_in) = "20" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 30
    WHEN b.t_in = "20:00" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "20" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 59 
    WHEN b.t_in = "21:00" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "21" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 59 
    WHEN b.t_in = "23:45" THEN HOUR(a.t_in) = "23" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 46 AND 59 OR HOUR(a.t_in) = "20" AND MINUTE(a.t_in) BETWEEN 01 AND 45
  ELSE 0 END 
  GROUP BY a.emp_id
  HAVING COUNT(a.emp_id) > 1
  ORDER BY f.loc, e.dept_id, c.last_name ASC
```

`working_schedule_03` table

```
CREATE TABLE `working_schedule_03` (
  `id` mediumint(99) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `m` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `d` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `y` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `emp_id` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `eve` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_in` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_out` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `emp_file` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `dt_plot` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=612993 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

`attendance_03` table

```
CREATE TABLE `attendance_03` (
  `a_id` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_in` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_b1_out` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_b1_in` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_lb_out` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_lb_in` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_b2_out` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_b2_in` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `t_out` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `mu` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `mm` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `dd` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `yy` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `d_out` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `d_b1_out` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `d_b1_in` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `d_lb_out` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `d_lb_in` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `d_b2_out` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `d_b2_in` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `emp_id` varchar(99) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. Are you using both MS SQL Server and MySQL here?

Comment: do you have any solution for this?

Comment: No, but I find some odd things. 1) if you have outer table conditions in the where clause, that outer join works like a regular inner join. 2) The general group by rule says "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding INDEXes will speed it up significantly:

- `working_schedule_03` would benefit from `INDEX(Y, d, eve)`.
- `attendance_03` would benefit from `INDEX(emp_id, dd)`.
- `employee_personal_info` and `employee_information`: `INDEX(emp_id)`.
- `departments`: `INDEX(e.dept_id)`
- `employee_location`: `INDEX(f.l_id)`

Get rid of `LEFT` unless you expect the 'right' table to be missing matching rows.

The second occurrence of `AND  b.eve = "Regular"` is redundant (because of the first).

The subquery says `SELECT *`.  It would be less stuff to haul around if you list only the necessary values (`emp_id, t_in, d`).

I gag on other things:

- Don't use `VARCHAR` for numbers.
- Consider using `TIME` for times.  (But there may be an issue with the `:00` seconds.)
- The big `CASE` could almost be turned into

  a.t_in >= b.t_in AND a.in < b.t_in + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE
- Check the output; the `COUNT(...)` may have a bigger value than needed.

Comment: this is some big infos that will optimize my sql query and minimize its execution time, i didn't created the table someone did, i'm just the one developing system out of it so... i'm the one fced up, can i still change modify the column structure if there are millions of records?

Comment: See `ALTER TABLE` for how to change the structure of an existing table.  But note that it will lock the table for some time.